# Which software tool can I use to conduct EMI and EMC tests for ECG, EMG, Spirometer, RTPCR machine? What are the drawbacks of each?

Tags: windows, scientific-computing

Can I run the simulation for 10 hours and get data for a thousand years or something?

I have designed a PCB for all the applications named above and now we have to apply for certification which requires us to clear EMC and EMI tests.

Two approaches were determined:

1. Taking a PCB without components and putting varying currents and voltages through every trace while keeping inside a 3D antenna to map radiations in near and far field and then find mathematics to scale up and or down the results.
2. The second was to simulate the board on software. I was told that the drawback of that was that only a few seconds worth of data could be gathered.
   But that conclusion is based on a sample space of 1. Therefore, can you suggest more?

Comment: Welcome Shridhar!  Thank you for the updates to you interesting question.  Are you looking for recommendations for gratis (free of cost) or commercial software (or either)?  If commercial software, what is your price range?  Please update your question with this detail when you have a moment.  Thanks!

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket price is not a problem the company will take care of that and since this is first of a product line price is not a problem.

Comment: That's great info for our community to know so we can hopefully help you.  Can you add it to your question?